# std::list push back adds two elements instead of one

Tags: c++, list

I'm trying to add elements to a list, but can't figure out why the `push_back` method is repeating the last added element. To illustrate:

[image]

Each node object consists of a `data` and `head` field. In the code below, I iterate through an array of ints, create a new node to store each int, and `push_back` the element to the list `L`. The repeated node is always the last one added to the list (in the picture above when iteratror i=1)

```
void addElements(std::list<node>& L, int arr[],std::list<node>::iterator Itor,int size){ //array decays to pointer
    for (int i=1;i<size;i++){
        node* n = new node;
        n->data = arr[i];
        n->head = Itor->head; //head of the first element in the list
        L.push_back(*n);
    }
}
```

I included the complete code of the disjoint data structure below. I read on cplusplus.com that push_back increases the container size by 1. So I'm a little perplexed why an extra node is being added to the list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct node{
    int data;
    node* head;
};

void makeSet(std::list<node>& L,int arr[]){ //asterick is before the variable name
    node *headNode = new node;
    headNode->data = arr[0]; //representative node
    headNode->head = headNode; //point to itself
    L.push_back(*headNode);
}

void addElements(std::list<node>& L, int arr[],std::list<node>::iterator Itor,int size){ //array decays to pointer
    for (int i=1;i<size;i++){
        node* n = new node;
        n->data = arr[i];
        n->head = Itor->head; //head of the first element in the list
        L.push_back(*n);
    }
}

int findSet(node* element){
    return element->head->data;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::list<node>List;
    std::list<node>::iterator Itor;
    int dataArr[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int size = sizeof(dataArr)/sizeof(dataArr[0]);
    Itor = List.begin();
    makeSet(List,dataArr);
    addElements(List,dataArr,Itor,size);
    for (Itor = List.begin();Itor!=List.end();Itor++){
        std::cout << Itor->data << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: in C++ `new` is close to a last resort. Most of the time you don't need it, you don't need it here, and when you do you should use a smart pointer to ensure it is `delete`ed.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does this `Node` represent?

Comment: can't I delete the entire list when my program is done?

Comment: I'm trying to create a disjoint data structure. Basically, a bunch of values stored in nodes, each of which has a pointer to the head of the list for easy identification of which set the node is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the size of the list in your example is 2. This means only nodes 0 and 1 are valid. This extra duplicate link is likely a [Sentinel Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

Often you'll find linked lists terminate with a null pointer, but it's just as easy to define the end of the list as a link that points to itself. This may have additional advantages, such as providing a one-past-the-end link to return as `list::end`.

Whatever its benefits, it is outside the bounds of the list so best that you not mess with it.

Comment: how is the size of the list 2? when debugging `size` variable equals 5. Won't the list accommodate more elements as I add them?

Comment: @st4rgut the provided image shows `size` = 2, two valid links, and one duplicate link. The list will grow as you stuff more entries in, but the current size is 2. The third link is not yours, and almost certainly there for book-keeping purposes by the `list` implementation.